# How to setup russian input method in Mint 14 xfce 64-bit?

Tags: linux-mint, xfce, input-method

I'm using Mint 14 XFCE, 64-bit.

Struggling to setup cyrillic (Russian) input method.

Can someone point me good web resources regarding this?

Googling didn't help...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to do it using XFCE's keyboard settings. Run this command from a terminal:

```
xfce4-keyboard-settings
```

This should open the keyboard settings window, go to the "Layout" tab and click "Add":

[image]

Choose "Russian" in the window that appears

[image]

---

If for some reason the above fails, you can always switch layouts using

```
setxkbmap -layout ru
```