# How do I add other language in a Debian system?

Tags: debian, kde, locale

I want to add another language in Debian. I have done

```
dpkg-reconfigure locales
locale -a
C
C.UTF-8
en_US.utf8
POSIX
ru_RU.utf8
```

but I don't have any result.

```
root@ai:/home/volkov# locale
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=en_US:en
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

The field “System Settings → locale → Languages → available languages” is empty.
How do I fix it?

Comment: Do you want to be able to type in another language? To spell check? To display it correctly in the terminal? What Desktop Environment are you using? Have you seen [this](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/74438/22222)?

Comment: I want to type in another language. second and third options I don't need. The display is correctly now.

Comment: Desktop Environment is KDE

Comment: I added other language in Sysytem Setings -> locale -> Languages -> available languages at debian 6.5.0. now this field is empty. there only one english language.

Comment: You may need to install some language packs. Try `sudo apt-get install kde-l10n-ru`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to add another language to your KDE environment, you should install the appropriate language pack. For example, to get Russian run:

```
sudo apt-get install kde-l10n-ru
```